# Text geometry not changing size even after changing height and size parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have an issue with loading text in my react three fiber project, although the text renders ( because i see a very tiny pixel of the text color at the position i placed the text). But the text refuses to resize or become bigger to be seen properly and i've searched it seems like no one has faced this issue before,heres my code for the font loader for the text:

```
extend({ TextGeometry })

  const font = new FontLoader().load('node_modules/three/examples/fonts/droid/droid_sans_bold.typeface.json');
```

and code for rendering the text itself:

```
<mesh position={[-170,30,0]}>
      <textGeometry args={["DP LAYER", {font,size: 80,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 10,
      bevelSize: 8,
      bevelOffset: 0,
      bevelSegments: 5 }]}  />
      <meshBasicMaterial color="red" />
 </mesh>
```

not really sure of what can be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Your font parameter is not a object and therefor the options object may not work as intended...
[image]

should be:

```js
{font:font, size:80,
...
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but didn't work